# How do you know whether a node already exists in xml before adding another?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

From vba in my Excel workbook, I can execute the following many times:

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add("<authors><author>Christie</author><author>King</author></authors>")
```

and each time I do, it creates yet another CustomXMLPart which are all the same (apart from the standard which are automatically created!!).

My first question is, how do I determine whether author Christie is already in the list before I try and add her again?

Secondly, how do I use `item` with a named reference?

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Item({named reference})
```

What is the name I reference in the item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code snippet

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add ("<authors><author>Christie</author><author>King</author></authors>")
For Each xmlCustom In ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts
    Set nodeCheck = xmlCustom.SelectNodes("//author[text()='Christie']")
    If nodeCheck.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "already exist in collection"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = 4 To ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Count '1-3 are default xmlparts
    Set nodeCheck = ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Item(i).SelectNodes("//author[text()='King']")
    If nodeCheck.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "already exist in items"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

In the first part, I have gone through the collection using `for-each` which takes away the pain of knowing the upper/lower boundaries of a collection. The second part uses the iteration technique using each `item` of the collection